# Graphic Tablet Support

Tags: graphics, tablet

I am new to Ubuntu 14.04 and Linux in general. I am tired of Microsoft bloat-ware. I am in the process of delving into Ubuntu and graphical work using Inkscape, Gimp, and Blender. Most of the Tuts are on a Windows box and a lot of them use a graphics tablet. I have been thinking about buying a a graphics tablet myself, however most of them do not appear to support any Linux flavors and I see no where from my searches where Ubuntu will be supporting tablets and I really do not want to spend any money on something that will not do the job.

Any feedback from anyone with good ideas or suggestions would be great.

DaveC

Answer (score 1):

I am a graphic designer and interface designer who has recently become an Ubuntu user and was pleasantly surprised to find Wacom support built into Ubuntu 14.04 right out of the box. It also appears the driver can even be updated to more current versions than in the official Ubuntu Repositories if desired. In case you were wondering I am using an Intuos tablet, so I suppose I can't vouch for any other of the Wacom products, however I would likely assume that all their products (Minus maybe the centiq? But could be wrong) would work just fine here.